# Swap reversing a linked list in c

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, linked-list, iterator

Given a list, I want to reverse the list by swapping the first with the last, second with the second last and so on.

I wrote this function to swap each pair where `pos1` and `pos2` are the two positions to be swapped.

`maxPos` is the largest of the two positions,
`node1` and `node2` are the two nodes that were found after traversing the list.

```
int swap(struct node *list, int pos1, int pos2) {

    if (node1 != NULL && node2 != NULL) {
        if (prev1 != NULL)
            prev1->next = node2;
        if (prev2 != NULL)
            prev2->next = node1;
        temp        = node1->next;
        node1->next = node2->next;
        node2->next = temp;
        if (prev1 == NULL)
            head = node2;
        else if (prev2 == NULL)
            head = node1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Instead of calling this recursively for each pair, ie. `(1,n-1)`, `(2,n-2)`, `(3,n-3)` for which it has to traverse the list every time, I was wondering if there is a way for it to be solved iteratively.

Comment: Please make a [mcve] of the code working recursively, to provide a foundation for asking about the alternative solution. As is, there is not enough information on several details in your program. E.g. typedefs.

Comment: @Yunnosch I've cleaned it to be readable as much as I can. Thank you.

Comment: @Fredrik, I'm not sure how I can use a for loop in this case. Like the first and last element?

Comment: `calling this recursively for each pair, ie. (1,n-1), (2,n-2), (3,n-3)` that is not usually called *recursively*. A recursion might remember the outer nodes, apply itself to the list without those, and prepend the last, append the first node for its result. BUT: Given there *is* a nice iterative procedure to reverse a singly linked list, *why* create an inferior recursive one?

Comment: @Fredrik say the head is written as void **head and the memory have been allocated how will the for loop look like?

Comment: J Doe, the person you address personally has withdrawn the comment you are referring to. Probably (though not guaranteed) because of realising that they cannot uphold their claim. It would now be polite to delete your comment, too.

Comment: Do you want to swap node contents? Or do you want to reverse the list and store a pointer to the reversed list into the root pointer? It is very simple to reverse a list iteratively.

Comment: I put a proposal swapping the nodes (not their possible contents), as you can see this is more complicated than a standard reverse. As @chqrlie said the reverse is the right way

Comment: @JDoe why did you edited your question like that ? Now _pos1_ and _pos2_ are unused and it is almost impossible to understand what you request :-(

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You'll have to declare a new method for reversing the whole list that'll be called only once. Also you'd better use a doubly-linked list for this problem.

Node structure:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};
```

Method:

```
void reverse() {

    struct node *temp = head; // assuming you have the head node as a global variable.
    struct node *lastPtr = head;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) { // assuming you have length as a global variable.
        lastPtr = lastPtr->next;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
        temp->data += lastPtr->data;
        lastPtr->data = temp->data - lastPtr->data;
        temp->data -= lastPtr->data;
        temp = temp->next;
        lastPtr = lastPtr->prev;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MuhammedGui temp->data += lastPtr->data; what does this do? is it adding the value in the temp and lastPtr?

Comment: @JDoe Yes it is. That line and the following 2 lines are for swapping the datas between the two nodes.

Comment: So how does the struct node look like in this case?

struct node{ int data;
   struct node *next;} am I correct.

Comment: I assumed you are using a doubly-linked list since i used 'lastPtr->prev;'. So the struct node must be like: { int data; struct node *next; struct node *prev; } where 'prev' points to the previous node.

Comment: you do not answer to the question, you do not swap the cells but their values

Comment: @bruno 'I want to reverse the list' this is what he wants, and if you look his replies you can clearly understand he is beginner so he wouldn't want ask for swapping nodes. Also it is checked as 'solved', so your downvote is useless.

Comment: @MuhammedGül look at the OP code, do you see something about the data ? no, we don't even know if there is a data in the cell ;-)

Comment: @bruno fair enough but why would someone create a linked list without data ? So you say me to swap identical nodes?

Comment: @MuhammedGül you have to rewrite your code each time the 'data' change, its complexity depends on the number of fields composing the 'data' and the execution time depends on amount of memory supported by the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189360/discussion-between-muhammed-gul-and-bruno).

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to swap node contents?

You can reverse the list iteratively with a very simple function:

```
struct node {
    // whatever payload fields...
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *reverse_list(struct node *list) {
    struct node *last = NULL;
    while (list != NULL) {
        struct node *next = list->next;
        list->next = last;
        last = list;
        list = next;
    }
    return last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a list with an anchor element (e.g. the first element is a node but not used for storing data), you can use

```
struct node **list_nth(struct node *node, size_t idx)
{
    for (;idx > 0 && node; --idx)
        node = node->next;

    return node ? &(node->next) : NULL;
}

void list_swap(struct node *head, size_t idx_a, size_t idx_b)
{
    struct node **a = list_nth(head, min(idx_a, idx_b));
    struct node **b = list_nth(head, max(idx_a, idx_b));
    struct node *tmp;

    if (idx_a == idx_b)
        return;

    if (!a || !b)
        abort();

    if ((*a)->next == *b) {
        tmp = *a;

        *a  = *b;
        tmp->next = (*b)->next;
        (*a)->next = tmp;
    } else {
        tmp        = (*a)->next;
        (*a)->next = (*b)->next;
        (*b)->next = tmp;

        tmp = *a;
        *a  = *b;
        *b  = tmp;
    }
}
```

for the swap operation.  But for single linked lists, your reverse operation has a complexity of O(n^2) due to the expensive node lookup.

As noted somewhere else, for reversing a list:

- use a double-linked one
- iterate it in reverse with O(n)
- remove the element (O(1))
- append the element to a new head (O(1))
- merge the new list into the old one back (O(1))